# Touchpad one-finger directions are askew

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad

I just upgraded a Lenovo Laptop to Windows 10. For some reason, the trackpad is messed up and moving the cursor in the wrong direction. The cursor moves right when I go up, down when I go right, etc.

This only happens with one-finger gestures. With two-finger scrolling, everything works fine.

Naturally there is no setting under Mouse settings, Mouse advanced settings, or trackpad properties. What's the secret to putting it right and moving on with my day?

Comment: Have you install Windows 10 touchpad drivers on the device? If not, go the OEM website, and download them.  If its not there go the touchpad manfature's website and download the generic Windows 10 drivers

Comment: I might try that. I am pretty sure it was working immediately after it upgraded, and no issue is reported in Device Manager. Wouldn't hurt to try though.